# Memory fragmentation

Tags: c, memory, malloc, memory-fragmentation

When I use `malloc()`s and `free()`s randomly, nested and with different sizes, at some point the memory will be fragmented because these operations leave a large list of small memory areas behind that are non-contiguous and therefore can't be allocated as one bigger piece.

A few questions on this:

- When this is done quite often so that memory is forced to be fragmented and then *all* these memory areas are `free()`d, can I assume these free areas are concatenated back to its original, contiguous size?
- When I always do a `malloc()` followed by `free()` for the same memory and never nest these calls, is the memory fragmented in this scenario too when allocated/freed sizes are always different?

Comment: All this is implementation dependant. But, yes, a good memory manager will concatenate contiguous free memory portions. And, yes, if you do a `malloc` followed by a `free` and you don't call any library functions that call `malloc` in between , then no fragmentation should occur.

Comment: You can run Valgrind with your program http://www.valgrind.org and check for data alignment errors and memory leaks.

Comment: It's quite hard to fragment a 64 bit address space. Sure, you can easily fragment it to the point where you can't allocate a 10 TB object anymore, but you probably didn't have 10 TB RAM anyway.

Comment: 1. no. 2. no. If the memory allocator does ASLR it might actively avoid being as predictable as you want it to be. The solution is to use an architecture with a large address space and ignore fragmentation, with 64 bit pointers and todays large memory sizes fragmentation is mostly yesterdays problem unless you have some very specific application.

Comment: How would that work anyway? C does not provide a garbage collection, less memory space compaction. It simply can't, as it there is no information about where pointers to objects exist.

Comment: @Olaf in theory this should not be a problem. The C-library should contain a list of pointers that mark the free/allocated memory areas and their sizes. A clever algorithm then could go through this list after every free() and concatenate single entries that point to memory areas that are located directly behind each other

Comment: @Elmi: Please read what "memory (space) compaction means. You talk about combining adjascent block, which is a different thing. That site is not to discuss how to implement a memory manager can/should be implemented. There is already enough information about this, including a plethora of source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per **ISO/IEC 9899:201x -> 7.22.3**

> The order and contiguity of storage allocated by successive calls to
>   the aligned_alloc, calloc, malloc, and realloc functions is
>   unspecified.

A good memory manager will be able to tackle the issue to an extent. However, there are other aspects like data alignment [[1]](http://www.memorymanagement.org/glossary/p.html) which causes internal fragmentation.

**What you could do if you rely on inbuilt memory management?**

1. Use a profiler - say valgrind - with memory check option to find the memory which is not freed after use.
   Example:

   ```
    valgrind --leak-check=yes myprog arg1 arg2
   ```
2. Follow good practices. Example - In C++, if you intend others to inherit from your polymorphic class, you may declare its destructor virtual.
3. Use smart pointers.

**Notes:**

1. [Internal fragmentation](http://www.memorymanagement.org/glossary/i.html#term-internal-fragmentation).
2. If you were to use your own memory management system, you may consider [Boehm-Demers-Weiser](http://hboehm.info/gc/) garbage collector.
3. [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)  Instrumentation Framework.
4. Memory not freed after use will contribute to fragmentation.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no guarantee. According to N1570, [7.22.3 Memory management functions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3):

> The order and contiguity of storage allocated by successive calls to
>   the aligned_alloc, calloc, malloc, and realloc functions is
>   unspecified.

Anyway, you have two choices to choose from:

1. Totally trust the library memory management functions.
2. Write you own memory managers, if you're **really** confident.

If I were you, I would definitely trust the existing functions, because modern implementations are super smart.

Comment: Actually, since the question is (also) tagged C++, the two possibilities are not mutually exclusive. You can override `operator new` on a class by class basis.